# Change subdomain link to another and keep content

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have 2 sub-domains, if the user navigate to sub-domain 1, keep the content, but change the URL to sub-domain 2. The following is not working for me, not sure about the best way of implementing this.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub1.domain.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://sub2.domain.com/$1 [P]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for this issue, I hope this will reach someone needs it.

```
RequestHeader set Host sub1.domain.com
RewriteRule membership/new-member-application/$ http://sub2.domain.com/member/newmemberapp/ [P,L]
```